# Android: Making a complex interface

Tags: android, layout, drag-and-drop

I am a beginner at android app development. I have an idea of an app, but I first need to set my bearings straight. So instead of confusing you with the complexities of the app, I just want to ask a question. Obviously, I do not expect anyone to write me the entire code, instead just to guide me to the right path by indicating which methods, classes or keywords to look for.

I want to know how to create several instances of the same image. I am planning on having a toolbar with all the tools that you can select and then a workspace where you will be putting those tools. Ever played a tower defense games, you know how you have a toolbar with selection of towers to choose from and then you simply drag and drop them on the map? something like that. Please also guide me on which layout would best suit this type of application.

I understand the question is too broad, but any kind of help to get me started would immensely help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a game, you don't want to use native View objects.  Here's a [guide on Android game development](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1753131).

Here is a [simple example](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/the-abcs-of-android-game-development-animate-sprites/) of a Sprite based game for Android.

Comment: well technically its not a game, I am trying to build an application for electrical circuits...but i guess the same concepts would apply..thanks!

Comment: Vote up if it answers your question.  The example I listed (a chess game) is conceptually similar to an electrical circuit app in that it would likely be grid based and support drag and drop.

Comment: perfect but it says vote up requires 15 reputation points...this like my first post here so I am brand new

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that you are going the wrong way here. Just like if you wanted to build a house you wouldn't start from building the roof, first you need to **get a book** (I would recommend the Busy coders guide to android development) or start reading (or watching on youtube) a tutorial and just start learning to code in android. Get better at it and in some time you will understand better on what and how you can do with the platform. There are tons of stuff for you to learn before you will be able to do even simple stuff, but believe me learning android is very exciting and the feeling you get when developing an app should be what drives you forward. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply, the fact is I have taken a few programming classes before..but i have mostly worked with embedded systems...so its not that i am complete beginner at programming...and yes I have also gone through a lot of tutorials on android development, but the things that i mentioned are kinda advanced...so long story short, I take ur advice intor consideration haha thanks!